# Google Map iframe - cache issue

Tags: google-maps

We have a PHP page that uses iframes as created by the Google Maps link feature. The Google Map being displayed is a KML file from our web site.

http://www.slocleanair.org/air/AirForcasting_map3.php shows the two maps.

The URL displayed is created via PHP script when the page loads so that the link points to 'todays' forecast. The six days of forecasts are uploaded weekdays and the KML filenames include the date. We add a &time=xxxx parameter to the URL to make it unique for each page load. This is a very low volume application.

Our problem is if we bungle today's forecast and need to upload a new version of the KML we cannot see the new version. It appears that the time parameter is not busting cache as we would like. It does not appear that local cache is being used as the problem appears across browsers and PCs.

Is the map being cached by Google? If so how can we force a refresh short of renaming the file?

I suppose our web server could be caching as well - if so might there be a generic way to force our server to refresh its cache? If this is even a possibility I can contact them for specific help - is this cache point even possible?

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to add some meta tags to the page: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE"> <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`

Comment: I'll see if I can do that - our site uses a CMS so I may not be able to get to <meta>. Since the problem goes across browsers and manually clear cache does not work, I kind of doubt this will be the final answer.